# Inserir texto no selo verde SSL

Tags: ssl, https

Bom dia!

Alguém sabe como troco o texto que fica no selo verde ali do SLL http://image.prntscr.com/image/7fde1a30553545afa959a231886975b6.png

No caso, o meu normal so fica assim: http://image.prntscr.com/image/6024fa14b99a4b949d747e109b705067.png

Se não for trocar, alguém saberia explicar o que é e quem pode ter? Obrigado!

Meu certificado SSL é do Comodo Secure.

Abs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa de um Certificado de Validação Estendida (EV SSL). É o mais alto nível da validação de um certificado, porém é o mais caro. Para ter um você vai precisar ter um negócio válido, com telefone, endereço físico e um registro legal, que será consultado em órgãos públicos.

[Extended Validation Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)

Comment: Falai Lucas, procura explicar resposta aqui no site ( no seu post-resposta), quando colocamos links, num futuro proximo eles podem ficar quebrados, e ai perdemos o conteudo da resposta.

Comment: Valeu Andre, editei com mais informações e alterei o link.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas! Tudo de bom!